# How can I test chained React hooks in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, xmlhttprequest, react-dom

I have a component that is a simple form. It has an `input`, and when a user enters certain values, it will make an API call with that value to get an array of options with which it will then populate a `select`.

I'm able to test changes to the input without any problems - by simulating events I am able to get the first hook to execute.

But my issue is that I have two `useEffect` hooks chained off each other. Since the internals of the first hook are being mocked, I don't know how I can get it to trigger the second hook and render new results.

Here is a reduced version of the two hooks I am using:

```
Component.tsx

React.useEffect(() => {
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', `${api}?arg=${inputValue}`, true);
      request.onload = (e: ProgressEvent) => {
        const res = e.target as XMLHttpRequest;
        if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 400) {
          const data = JSON.parse(res.response);
          setList(data.list);
          }
        }
      };
      request.send();
  }, [inputValue]);

...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    select.current.innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>';
    if (list.length > 1) {
      list.forEach((item) => {
        select.current.innerHTML += `<option value="${item.name}">${item.name}</option>`;
      });
    }
  }, [list]);
```

So, when the inputValue changes, the component has to retrieve a new list. When the list changes, the options in the `<select>` are updated.

Currently I am mocking the XMLHttpRequest in a way similar to what's  described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893305/

How can I write mock this request in a way that triggers an internal change such that the second hook will be executed? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: It looks like you are setting up to do some direct DOM manipulations, an anti-pattern in React. You could probably do a small amount of refactoring to render UI in a more React-y way, and remove completely the second `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @DrewReese That's fair. I don't think it solves my problem, but it does help me narrow down what my actual problem is.

Regardless of how the DOM gets manipulated after the state is changed, I don't know how to trigger the necessary state change within the mocked XHR.

Answer (score 0):

I can leave this for posterity in case anyone gets as confused as I was, but the best solution was refactoring.

The easiest thing for me to do was replace the XHR with a fetch call. This allows me to save the response to a variable, and process it (save it to state) later. Then, in my test, I used a mock implementation of fetch to return the information I want, and I don't need to setState in a callback.

```
Component.tsx

const fetchOptions = async (input: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${api}?input=${input}`);
    const parsed: { list: IOption[] } = await response.json();
    setList(parsed.list)
  } catch (e) {
    setHasError(e)
  } finally {
    isRequesting = false;
  }

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (isRequesting) {
    return;
  }
  isRequesting = true;

  fetchOptions(value);
}, [inputValue]);
```

```
Component.test.js
...
const mockData = {
  list: [ { name: 'TEST' } ]
}

global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({
      json: () => mockData,
    });
  });
});
```

I put my exact mock implementation here because I also had quite a bit of difficulty figuring out the specific syntax required. Many guides (including the official docs) offered a mock implementation that did not work with my app.

Per Drew Reeses's suggestion, I also refactored my other hook to avoid direct DOM manipulation and instead used a reactive expression as a child of the select:

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
  { list?.map(item => <option value={item.name} key={item.id}>{item.name}</option> }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to testing components with hooks, it's generally easier (depending on the hook) to use [@testing-library/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react). It's a bit of a paradigm shift if you're used to `enzyme`.

Here's a decent article demonstrating it's use: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-test-custom-react-hooks.

A generic example for your use case would be

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

// == within test case ==

  const { rerender, result } = render(<Component {...props} />);
  
  // assert something
  
  props.val = 'newVal';
  rerender(<Component {...props} />); // updates current component with new props

  // assert changes
```

You'll use `result.current` to verify the DOM result changed in a way that you expect.