# XMLHttpRequest mock - Jest mockImplementation doesn't create class with specified methods

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock XMLHttpRequest but without success. Based on [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893305/3978701) I've managed to do following:

```js
const xhrMockClass = () => ({
  open: jest.fn(),
  send: jest.fn(),
  setRequestHeader: jest.fn()
})

window.XMLHttpRequest = jest.fn().mockImplementation(xhrMockClass)

test("App works", async () => {
  const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'www.google.com');
});
```

However my `httpRequest` object doesn't have `open`, `send` or `setRequestHeader` methods. Why the mocked implementation doesn't work as intended?

Tests fails with following error:

> TypeError: httpRequest.open is not a function

Comment: Do you have `__mocks__` directory and `jest.config.js`? It works fine for me

Comment: No, I don't have. It's a new project. Should I have one? @slideshowp2